# Raspberry Pi DNS resolution fails after assigning static IP

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (running Ubuntu 16.04) that I want to be accessible over our company's intranet at a static IP address. I've done this by creating a file under `/etc/network/interfaces.d` with the following content:

```
auto enxb827ebf9dfb5
iface enxb827ebf9dfb5 inet static
address 172.16.100.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 172.16.0.4
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I can connect to my RPi fine at this address. However, after having made this change I'm finding it doesn't seem to perform DNS resolution properly. For example, I can ping Google by running `nslookup` on another computer to find one of its addresses and running `ping <that_address>` on the RPi, but running `ping www.google.com` on the RPi won't work.

I can fix DNS resolution if I run `sudo systemctl restart networking` after each boot, but I'd like DNS resolution to automatically work like it was when it was configured to use DHCP.

Here's the current output of `ifconfig`:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:e3:eb:ae:57
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enxb827ebf9dfb5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f9:df:b5
          inet addr:172.16.100.1  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fef9:dfb5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3299020 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:449072 (449.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:184536 (184.5 KB)  TX bytes:184536 (184.5 KB)
```

**Edit**

Running `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` gives me the following output:

```
cups.path                                  enabled
accounts-daemon.service                    enabled
anacron-resume.service                     enabled
anacron.service                            enabled
autovt@.service                            enabled
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled
avahi-dnsconfd.service                     enabled
binfmt-support.service                     enabled
bluetooth.service                          enabled
brltty.service                             enabled
cron.service                               enabled
cups-browsed.service                       enabled
cups.service                               enabled
dbus-org.bluez.service                     enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service         enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service enabled
display-manager.service                    enabled
docker.service                             enabled
fake-hwclock.service                       enabled
friendly-recovery.service                  enabled
getty@.service                             enabled
hciuart.service                            enabled
lightdm.service                            enabled
ModemManager.service                       enabled
network-manager.service                    enabled
networking.service                         enabled
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service          enabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service         enabled
NetworkManager.service                     enabled
pppd-dns.service                           enabled
resolvconf.service                         enabled
rsyslog.service                            enabled
snapd.autoimport.service                   enabled
snapd.core-fixup.service                   enabled
snapd.service                              enabled
snapd.system-shutdown.service              enabled
ssh.service                                enabled
sshd.service                               enabled
sshdgenkeys.service                        enabled
syslog.service                             enabled
systemd-timesyncd.service                  enabled
tlp-sleep.service                          enabled
tlp.service                                enabled
ufw.service                                enabled
unattended-upgrades.service                enabled
ureadahead.service                         enabled
whoopsie.service                           enabled
apport-forward.socket                      enabled
avahi-daemon.socket                        enabled
cups.socket                                enabled
docker.socket                              enabled
snapd.socket                               enabled
uuidd.socket                               enabled
default.target                             enabled
graphical.target                           enabled
remote-fs.target                           enabled
runlevel5.target                           enabled
apt-daily-upgrade.timer                    enabled
apt-daily.timer                            enabled
snap-repair.timer                          enabled
snapd.refresh.timer                        enabled
```

Comment: just had a similar issue. in my case it ended up being a firewall, blocking the DNS requests.

Answer (score 1):

Is /etc/resolv.conf populated?

Example conf:

```
search home
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
options enxb827ebf9dfb5
```

Comment: It's empty apart from comments. `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`.

Comment: I should replace it with what you've posted?

Comment: Try it, then run 'systemctl restart networking'.

Comment: Also try: 'ip link set enxb827ebf9dfb5 down && ip link set enxb827ebf9dfb5 up' after 'systemctl restart networking'.

Comment: Sorry, if that doesn't work. I'm not the best with networking. :3

Comment: Editing the first three lines of your post into `resolv.conf` works, except after reboot these changes are overwritten (as it warns will happen).

Comment: So internet works, but when you reboot the file gets rewritten?

Comment: A service that starts at boot would be rewriting the file.

Comment: Using systemd you can list the services that start at boot using: 'systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled'

Comment: No issues with internet access in general, just DNS resolution. Modifying `resolv.conf` does make it work, but it gets overwritten on boot and I don't think modifying it directly is a good idea. I'll update my post with the output of the systemctl command.

Comment: Because /etc/resolv.conf overrides /etc/network/interfaces config, it is vital that /etc/resolv.conf doesn't have settings that stop the /etc/network/interfaces config from working. (Such as: 'nameserver 127.0.0.1'.)